# Cannot connect NodeJS to socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

This my NodeJS application setup

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const http = require("http");
const app = require("./app");
// const socketIO = require("socket.io");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
```

```js
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4001;
const server = http.createServer(app);
// In case server and client run on different URLs.
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  },
});
```

I think this `io.on("connection")` should called

```js
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("client connected: ", socket.id);
  socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
    console.log("Client disconnected:", socket.id, "Reason:", reason);
  });
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.info(`Server is start on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

NodeJS is not connecting socket.io. Please help me.

Comment: It should if a client connects. Has a client connected?

Comment: Thank you sir, after client connects it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code seems to be fine, your job now is to connect between client and server to enable socket.io. If you use ReactJS you can try:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = socketIOClient('http://localhost:4000');

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Connected to the server.');
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('Disconnected from the server.');
    });

    // Handle custom events here

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  return <div>Your React.js application</div>;
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be fine to me. Have you tried connecting to your server with a **client?**. Then only it will show as connected. Here is an example client you can use to connect to localhost. Save this as `index.html`

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Socket.io Client</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Example socket.io client</h1>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  const socket = io();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```